# Google sheet script - Filtering unique cell values - Pushing 2D array values into a single cell

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filtering, unique

sorry to disturb again but I'm getting my head off..
I just want to filter unique strings that are in each cell of a range (strings are separated by semicolons)
I can't push all the array values, only one is getting out of results.
Thanks a lot !

Here is an example : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12T5K9LovcFvmeBg82IS89p4ygtZ530mzpY9fIsZQa8w/edit?usp=sharing
PS : I'm using script because they are too many strings in each cell for spliting cell by formula

Here's my coding :

```
function FilterReferences(){

  var classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var feuille = classeur.getSheetByName('Feuille 1');
  var plage = feuille.getRange('A1:A');
  var plageValues = plage.getValues();
  var NbLignesTotal = plage.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 1; i < NbLignesTotal; i++){
    try {
       var valeurCellule = plageValues[i-1][0];
        if (valeurCellule != ""){
          var source = valeurCellule.split(";");
          var dest = [];
          dest.push(source[0]);

          for (var n = 0 ; n < source.length ; n++){
          if (dest.indexOf(source[n]) == -1){  dest.push(source[n])};   }


        var plageDest = feuille.getRange('B1:B');
        plageDest.getCell(i,1).setValue([dest]);

     }
    } catch (e) {   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to achieve the following situation. Each value is put in a cell.

  - `AAA;BBB;AAA;BBB;CCC` to `AAA;BBB;CCC`
  - `AAA;CCC;AAA;DDD;ZZZ;CCC` to `AAA;CCC;DDD;ZZZ`

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your script is modified.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
plageDest.getCell(i,1).setValue([dest]);
```

To:

```
plageDest.getCell(i + 1, 1).setValue(dest.join(";"));
```

- In your script, `dest` is an array. So in order to convert it to a string, `join` is used.

  - When `plageDest.getCell(i,1).setValue([dest]);` is run, the 1st element is put by `setValue`. I think that this is the reason of your issue.
- In order to put the value from the row 2, `i + 1` is used instead of `i`.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, your script is modified by reducing the process cost.

#### Modified script:

```
function FilterReferences() {
  var classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var feuille = classeur.getSheetByName('Feuille 1');
  var plage = feuille.getRange('A2:A' + feuille.getLastRow());  // Modified
  var plageValues = plage.getValues();

  // I added below script.
  const res = plageValues.map(([e]) => 
    [Object.keys(e.split(";").reduce((o, e) =>
      Object.assign(o, {[e]: null})
    , {})).join(";")]
  );
  feuille.getRange(2, 2, res.length, 1).setValues(res);
}
```

- In this script, the values are created in the loop. And then, the created values are put to the cells using `setValues`.

### References:

- [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Thank you very very very much for the tip and your extra solution, it now works like a charm ! Life bless you

Comment: @Nad Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Don't really understand why the need to convert to string, but I take for granted.Thank you again

Comment: @Nad Thank you for replying. In your situation, the converted value is put in a cell. So I proposed to convert to the string and put it using `setValue` at the pattern 1.